# Difference between facetious, frivolous and flippant?

Tags: meaning, differences

These three words have nearly identical meaning. The meanings of these words according to Google are

**Facetious:** treating serious issues with deliberately inappropriate humor; flippant.

**Flippant:** not showing a serious or respectful attitude.

**Frivolous:** not having any serious purpose or value.

If I take these definitions, the words **"Flippant"** and **"Frivolous"** seems to be used in a pejorative sense, while Facetious seems a bit "lighthearted" type of characteristic. 
I am not a native speaker. Are these true of the words or am I over-analyzing similar words. Are there any differences between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Frivolous** -- Frivolous can be used as a negative, but it's *also* quite commonly used in the context of pursuing something that may be entertaining or fun, but has no practical value -- for example, a frivolous purchase would be something you buy that makes you feel good, but that you don't actually *need*.  People will more often acknowledge that they do something *frivolously* than either flippantly or facetiously, and it tends to be framed as a half-positive -- something like --

> "I know it was a little bit frivolous, but don't you just love it?"

**Flippant** -- this is the one that's most often used critically, usually in the context where someone is dismissing something genuinely serious with a play at humor.  For example, someone might be criticised for their flippant dismissal of a serious political issue.

> The gentleman's flippant remarks about the Middle East drew ire from the opposition.

**Facetious** -- This is probably the least widely used of the three, but refers more directly to being humorous than the other two.  Most often, I've heard it used almost as a disclaimer about something someone is about to say, in the line of:

> I don't mean to be facetious, but...

Which is similar to saying "I don't mean to be funny", or "I don't mean to make a joke", and then proceeding from there.

Comment: Even though there was a great answer that referred directly to dictionary, I accepted this answer, because I was looking for a more subjective explanation and this answered what I was looking for. Hope this is an acceptable practice in the community.

Comment: when you're facetious, commonly you could be interpreted as being rude. (Whether you mean to or not, as in your example "I don't mean to be facetious, but...)

Comment: Very much so!  I probably should have been clearer about that in my answer -- the reason to make such a statement is usually because you know you may come across that way.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the three words are fairly different.

You are correct that **Facetious** is often very lighthearted. In fact, it actually comes from the Latin word for jest. If I were to make a sarcastic joke about tearing down my house because I found a large spider, I would be speaking facetiously.

Being **Flippant** can come in a variety of forms. Most often, it is a carelessness of attitude. People can often become flippant in an attempt to be playfully facetious. It is used to describe an uncaring attitude. If a friend of mine were dying, and I made a joke about it, I would be speaking flippantly.

**Frivolous** is a term used less to describe an attitude, but more of an action, and is often used in the context of finances. If I were to spend all of my money on a guitar collection, when I don't even play guitar, I would be spending my money frivolously.

**Flippant** can often be used in place of **Frivolous**, but almost never can **Frivolous** be used in place of **Flippant**

Comment: Welcome to the ELU.SE! This is good first answer. One small suggestion might be to add sourced and cited definitions from a reputable dictionary to boost your argument.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the advice. I will certainly keep it in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2):

The three words are generally pejorative. Here are the differences:

Facetious refers to speech or writing using the bite of **ironic humor** to address serious issues without respect — even flippantly or frivolously.

[Collins English Dictionary, 12th Ed.:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/facetious)

> characterized by levity of attitude and love of joking, jocular or amusing

Flippant refers to speech or writing that is **cute**, without showing a serious attitude about a serious matter. As such, more dignity is expected: *When interviewing, you are better off saying you don't know than giving a flippant answer*.

[American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flippant)

> marked by disrespectful levity or casualness

Frivolous refers to **lacking in substance** or seriousness: *the frivolous talk of gossip and rumor*. A lawsuit brought to court for a small broken promise may well be *dismissed as a frivolous lawsuit*.

[American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Frivolous)

> unworthy of serious attention; trivial, inappropriately silly

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an oversimplifications, but let's differentiate them by using synonyms:

- **Facetious** is a synonym of **sarcastic**: "When the security officer asked her if she had any weapons in her tiny purse, her *facetious* response nearly got her in big trouble."
- **Flippant** is a synonym of **unserious** (if that's a word): "Joe, your low grades are a direct result of your *flippant* attitude about homework."
- **Frivolous** is a synonym of **unnecessary** or maybe **extravagant**: "Sure, that purchase was a bit *frivolous*, but I just love pretty hats!"